# Convert datedate format SQLSERVER

Tags: sql-server

I have following value in my table

```
2017-04-05 10:30:00:000
```

I am not able to convert this to the below format

```
5 April, 10:30 AM
```

I need to this thru query only. Please help.

Comment: What have you tried? If this is SQL Server, you need to look up `CONVERT` or `FORMAT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sql server 2012+ you can use [**`format()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx):

```
select format(getdate(), 'dd MMMMM, hh:mm tt')
```

Prior to 2012 you can use this

```
select convert(varchar(2),getdate(),113) 
     + ' ' + datename(month,getdate())
     + ', '+ stuff(right(convert(varchar(24),getdate(),100),6),5,0,' ')
```

(note: at this time, this question is tagged sql-server, previously it looks like it was tagged for mysql)

Comment: Thanks this works, yeah initially i tagged it wrong. Thanks to other guys as well for their time

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 select date_format('2017-04-05 10:30:00:000', '%d %M %H:%i %p');
```

This is the result:

```
05 April 10:30 AM
```

Have a look at [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) on MySql docs.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2017-04-05 10:30:00:000', '%d %M, %r');
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2017-04-05 10:30:00:000', '%d %M, %r');
+----------------------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT('017-04-05 10:30:00:000', '%d %M, %r') |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| 05 April, 10:30:00 AM                              |
+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 0 warning (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this link to be very useful for customizing different date formats in SQL Server.

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Here's the long and short of it:

```
Date Format     Standard    SQL Statement   Sample Output
Mon DD YYYY 1
HH:MIAM (or PM)     Default     SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100)     Jan 1 2005 1:29PM 1
MM/DD/YY    USA     SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 1) AS [MM/DD/YY]  11/23/98
MM/DD/YYYY  USA     SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101) AS [MM/DD/YYYY]     11/23/1998
YY.MM.DD    ANSI    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 2) AS [YY.MM.DD]  72.01.01
YYYY.MM.DD  ANSI    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 102) AS [YYYY.MM.DD]     1972.01.01
DD/MM/YY    British/French  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 3) AS [DD/MM/YY]  19/02/72
DD/MM/YYYY  British/French  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY]     19/02/1972
DD.MM.YY    German  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 4) AS [DD.MM.YY]  25.12.05
DD.MM.YYYY  German  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 104) AS [DD.MM.YYYY]     25.12.2005
DD-MM-YY    Italian     SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 5) AS [DD-MM-YY]  24-01-98
DD-MM-YYYY  Italian     SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105) AS [DD-MM-YYYY]     24-01-1998
DD Mon YY 1     -   SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), GETDATE(), 6) AS [DD MON YY]     04 Jul 06 1
DD Mon YYYY 1   -   SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 106) AS [DD MON YYYY]    04 Jul 2006 1
Mon DD, YY 1    -   SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 7) AS [Mon DD, YY]   Jan 24, 98 1
Mon DD, YYYY 1  -   SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 107) AS [Mon DD, YYYY]   Jan 24, 1998 1
HH:MM:SS    -   SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108)  03:24:53
Mon DD YYYY HH:MI:SS:MMMAM (or PM) 1    Default +
milliseconds    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), GETDATE(), 109)     Apr 28 2006 12:32:29:253PM 1
MM-DD-YY    USA     SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 10) AS [MM-DD-YY]     01-01-06
MM-DD-YYYY  USA     SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110) AS [MM-DD-YYYY]     01-01-2006
YY/MM/DD    -   SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 11) AS [YY/MM/DD]     98/11/23
YYYY/MM/DD  -   SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111) AS [YYYY/MM/DD]     1998/11/23
YYMMDD  ISO     SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), GETDATE(), 12) AS [YYMMDD]   980124
YYYYMMDD    ISO     SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) AS [YYYYMMDD]    19980124
DD Mon YYYY HH:MM:SS:MMM(24h) 1     Europe default + milliseconds   SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), GETDATE(), 113)     28 Apr 2006 00:34:55:190 1
HH:MI:SS:MMM(24H)   -   SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 114) AS [HH:MI:SS:MMM(24H)]  11:34:23:013
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS(24h)    ODBC Canonical  SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 120)     1972-01-01 13:42:24
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.MMM(24h)    ODBC Canonical
(with milliseconds)     SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE(), 121)     1972-02-19 06:35:24.489
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS:MMM     ISO8601     SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), GETDATE(), 126)     1998-11-23T11:25:43:250
DD Mon YYYY HH:MI:SS:MMMAM 1    Kuwaiti     SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), GETDATE(), 130)     28 Apr 2006 12:39:32:429AM 1
DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS:MMMAM   Kuwaiti     SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), GETDATE(), 131)     28/04/2006 12:39:32:429AM

Here are some more date formats that does not come standard in SQL Server as part of the CONVERT function.
Extended Date Formats
Date Format     SQL Statement   Sample Output
YY-MM-DD    
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120), 3, 8) AS [YY-MM-DD]
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 11), '/', '-') AS [YY-MM-DD]
    99-01-24
YYYY-MM-DD  
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120) AS [YYYY-MM-DD]
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 111), '/', '-') AS [YYYY-MM-DD]
    1999-01-24
MM/YY   SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 3), 5) AS [MM/YY]
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 3), 4, 5) AS [MM/YY]    08/99
MM/YYYY     SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103), 7) AS [MM/YYYY]  12/2005
YY/MM   SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), GETDATE(), 11) AS [YY/MM]    99/08
YYYY/MM     SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), GETDATE(), 111) AS [YYYY/MM]     2005/12
Month DD, YYYY 1    SELECT DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()) + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 107), 9) AS [Month DD, YYYY]     July 04, 2006 1
Mon YYYY 1  SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 113), 4, 8) AS [Mon YYYY]  Apr 2006 1
Month YYYY 1    SELECT DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS [Month YYYY]  February 2006 1
DD Month 1  SELECT CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' ' + DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()) AS [DD Month]     11 September 1
Month DD 1  SELECT DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()) + ' ' + CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS [Month DD]     September 11 1
DD Month YY 1   SELECT CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' ' + DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()) + ' ' + RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)), 2) AS [DD Month YY]    19 February 72 1
DD Month YYYY 1     SELECT CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' ' + DATENAME(MM, GETDATE()) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS [DD Month YYYY]    11 September 2002 1
MM-YY   SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 5), 5) AS [MM-YY]
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 5), 4, 5) AS [MM-YY]    12/92
MM-YYYY     SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105), 7) AS [MM-YYYY]  05-2006
YY-MM   SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), GETDATE(), 120), 5) AS [YY-MM]
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120), 3, 5) AS [YY-MM]     92/12
YYYY-MM     SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), GETDATE(), 120) AS [YYYY-MM]     2006-05
MMDDYY  SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 1), '/', '') AS [MMDDYY]     122506
MMDDYYYY    SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101), '/', '') AS [MMDDYYYY]     12252006
DDMMYY  SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 3), '/', '') AS [DDMMYY]     240702
DDMMYYYY    SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103), '/', '') AS [DDMMYYYY]     24072002
Mon-YY 1    SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), GETDATE(), 6), 6), ' ', '-') AS [Mon-YY]   Sep-02 1
Mon-YYYY 1  SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 106), 8), ' ', '-') AS [Mon-YYYY]  Sep-2002 1
DD-Mon-YY 1     SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), GETDATE(), 6), ' ', '-') AS [DD-Mon-YY]  25-Dec-05 1
DD-Mon-YYYY 1   SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 106), ' ', '-') AS [DD-Mon-YYYY]     25-Dec-2005 1
```